# jqgrid:cancel deleting row(s)

Tags: jqgrid

I use jqgrid for my data, and enable user to delete rows from the grid. but when user click 'delete' button, jqgrid will popup a 'Delete' dialog to ask user if they wanna delete or cancel, how can i check if user choose 'cancel" before i really submit data deletion to the server? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would think the grid would only send the request if "OK" is clicked. You can use Firebug's "Net" tab to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

checked, no, it send the request as soon as i click 'delete' button...

Comment: This needs to be added as a comment to Justin's answer, not as an answer to your question.